# When I try to convert a hex string to an integer in JavaScript, I don't get the same number as I do in python

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I've been trying to convert a hex string to an integer in JavaScript but the number I get isn't the same as the number I get in python.

Here's my code in JS:

```
var x = CryptoJS.MD5('h').toString();
BigInt(parseInt(x, 16));
```

Here's what I get:

```
49268479078006859472353325704298889216n
```

And when I run this in python:

```
int(hashlib.md5('h'.encode()).hexdigest(), 16)
```

I get:

```
49268479078006861543109070154241760913
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` has already lost the precision for you by converting to a number before you convert to `BigInt`.

You can use… a `0x` prefix? It seems weird, like there’s a missing `BigInt.parse` API, but there you go.

```
BigInt('0x' + x)
```